# Multiple Divs to hide with checkbox and day

Tags: html, checkbox, hide, show

I'm writing an html about a list of restaurant and i would like the user has the possibility to show, if he wish, the restaurant open in the day.

As example, I put a restaurant into a div, so 5 div for 5 restaurant.

I have a Checkbox to permit to hide the restaurant closed when flagged.

but how i can handle to hide all the divs with same closed day (day of closing corresponding to system date using getday() ) when the checkbox is flagged?

In my mind, i have a code written that when checkbox is flagged, a variable XX will have a value Z for day and a variable YY will have a value "display: none;".

Any suggestions?

In the example below, let's suppose we are on monday, I flag the checkbox and restaurant 1, 4 and 5 will not be shown

```
<div id="restaurant 1" style=""> <!-- main div for restaurant 1 -->
        .........       <!-- closed on monday, so value 1 from getday() -->         
</div>
<div id="restaurant 2" style=""> <!-- main div for restaurant 2 -->
    .........           <!-- closed on saturday, so value 6 from getday() -->       
</div>
<div id="restaurant 3" style=""> <!-- main div for restaurant 3 -->
    .........               <!-- closed on friday, so value 5 from getday() --> 
</div>
<div id="restaurant 4" style=""> <!-- main div for restaurant 4 -->
    .........           <!-- closed on monday, so value 1 from getday() -->     
</div>     
<div id="restaurant 5" style=""> <!-- main div for restaurant 5 -->
    .........           <!-- closed on monday, so value 1 from getday() -->     
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here using the stack snippet: `<>` in the editor.We want to see the code you tried. For example you need JavaScript but have not tagged it

Comment: In real i don't have a code working, i tried to adapt coding find here in Stackoverflow.com but with no results

Comment: So show some effort. We do not write code for you but will help you with code you wrote :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the way to get the result i whished.
please check if it's ok also for you.
it needs to add a div class; in the example i add text_container+number of the day (text_container0 for sunday closing up to text_container6 for saturday) for each restaurant 
Tks to [Alexican](https://alexcican.com/post/hide-and-show-div/) for the hide/show method
[Mudassar Khan](http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Show-Hide-DIV-with-TextBox-when-CheckBox-is-checked-unchecked-using-jQuery.aspx) for the check/uncheck about checkboxes
[W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) for days choice.
So, tks to them, i wrote the following code :
HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.__cfRocketOptions = {byc:0,p:0,petok:"4e61817aa8cc99a086afc531fd10f5ff4e7b528a-1518422018-1800"};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/b7ef205d/cloudflare-static/rocket.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>

<label for="choice">
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice" />
    On OFF
</label>

<div id="container_2">
<p class="info">TEST Restaurant</p>

<div class="text_container1">
<div class="text_container">
<h2>Restaurant 1</h2>
<div>
<p>Closed on Monday ... 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="text_container0">
<div class="text_container">
<h2>Restaurant 2</h2>
<div>
<p>Closed on Sunday --- 0</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="text_container7">
<div class="text_container">
<h2>Restaurant 3</h2>
<div>
<p>Closed on Saturday ... 7</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="text_container1">
<div class="text_container">
<h2>Restaurant 4</h2>
<div>
<p>Closed on Monday ... 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/rocketscript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.text_container').addClass("visible");
<!--                 var d = new Date();-->
                <!--  var n = d.getDay();  --> 
             $("#choice").click(function () {
              if ($("#choice").is(":checked")) {

              switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
                       $('.text_container0').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        break;
    case 1:
                       $('.text_container1').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        break;
    case 2:
                       $('.text_container2').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        break;
    case 3:
                       $('.text_container3').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        break;
    case 4:
                       $('.text_container4').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        break;
    case 5:
                       $('.text_container5').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        break;
    case 6:
                       $('.text_container6').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
}
           <!-- $('.text_container1').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden"); -->
               } else {
               $('.text_container0').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
               $('.text_container1').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
               $('.text_container2').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
               $('.text_container3').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
               $('.text_container4').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
               $('.text_container5').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
               $('.text_container6').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        };
      });
     });
  </script>
</body>
```

more two simple CSS Line

```
    .visible>div {
  display: block;
  }

.hidden>div {
  display: none
}
```